# How to fix flatpack addon overriding ubuntu universe sources?

Tags: xubuntu, gnome-software

After a recent update of Xubuntu  'Software' (gnome-software) was replaced with 'Snap store'. So I uninstalled 'Snap store' and manually installed gnome-software.

In gnome-software I now have the Ubuntu universe packages and snap packages available. I decided to [add flatpak support](https://www.flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/). I installed the gnome-software flatpak plugin and also added the flathub.org repo.

The problem is that the gnome-software only shows snaps and flatpaks. The Ubuntu universe packages are not shown. After removing the flatpak support add on I started seeing the Ubuntu universe packages. Then tried to remove the snap add-on and leave the flatpak add-on. In that case I saw only flatpak packages. Which means the override the Ubuntu universe source somehow.